# Place 2 decimals on label in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to have 2 decimal places set after displayed number.

.h

```
- (IBAction)CalculateSpeed:(id)sender; {
int iSliderValue = [_sliKilometre value];
[_lblCelsiusValue setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", iSliderValue]];
int iFahrenheit = iSliderValue * 1*0.621371192;
[_lblFahrenheitValue setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.2f", iFahrenheit]]; }
```

Comment: This is not related to Xcode by any means. Apart from that, use `float`, `%.2f`, and read good beginners' C book (this is very basic). [Start here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.


Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
NSString* twoDecimalPointString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", floatNumber];
```

It's `%.02f` that's important.